# Font awsome icons are not showing

Tags: reactjs, django, font-awesome

In return () i used fa fa-pencil-square and fa fa-trash-o but icons are not showing. why its not showing the particular icons from font awsome?

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ListGroup, Card, Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import API from "./API";


   

 
            <tbody>
              {movies.map((movie, index) => {
                return (
                  <tr key="">
                    <th scope="row">{movie.id}</th>
                    <td> {movie.name}</td>
                    <td>{movie.genre}</td>
                    <td>{movie.starring}</td>
                    <td>
                      <i
                        className="fa fa-pencil-square text-primary d-inline"
                        aria-hidden="true" 
                        onClick={() => selectMovie(movie.id)}
                      ></i>
                      <i
                        className="fa fa-trash-o text-danger d-inline mx-3"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                        onClick={() => onDelete(movie.id)}
                      ></i>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMovie;
```

Comment: Does not seem to belong to the *free* set of icons. `square-pen` and `pen-to-square` do: https://fontawesome.com/search?q=pencil&o=r&m=free